# Fetch and Axios make an HTTP/1.1 request first before upgrading to HTTP/2 in react-native. Is there a way to directly connect using HTTP/2?

Tags: react-native, http2

I have a HTTP/2 server running in AWS. When I use my react native iOS app to connect to the server to fetch data using Axios or Fetch, the first request made by the the client is a HTTP/1.1 to which the server responds with [H2] upgrade response. From then on, the client makes HTTP/2 requests.

I want to avoid the first HTTP/1.1 request. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Are you using SSL?

Comment: @evert Yes. Does that matter ?

Comment: It does, because if you're using HTTPS urls, HTTP/2 _should_ be negotiated during the SSL negotation, therefore you should never see the initial HTTP/1.1 request. The HTTP/1.1 upgrade to H/2 only happens for non ssl connection as far as I know.

Comment: @evert I will investigate about that. Thanks for the info.